# In base R, change points color based on its y value

Tags: r

I have 10 set of data and I want to show the data in plot which the data are bigger than 1 show with red and smaller than 1 show with blue.

```
y<-c(19.2,18.3,17.1,17.3,16.8,16.5,15.8,15.2,15.2,14,14,13.8,13.6,12.8,18.5,17.3,16.3,16.3,16,16,15.7,15.5,15.3,15.3,14.8,14.3,14.3,14.2,14,13.8,12.5,11.5)
x2<-c(3.85,3.73,3.88,3.86,3.98,3.85,3.93,3.66,3.91,3.47,3.91,3.75,3.9,3.92,3.87,3.97,3.76,3.76,3.98,3.88,3.75,3.98,3.69,3.77,3.74,3.76,3.91,3.6,3.76,3.9,3.8,3.65)
x3<-c(66,79,73,99,75,61,66,86,78,178,81,108,92,96,89,59,22,77,58,85,120,94,122,144,10,100,73,301,104,67,89,192)
x4<-c(9.35,11.15,9.4,12.85,8.55,10.3,4.9,6.4,5.8,3.6,3.9,5.8,5.4,5,9.15,10.25,8.2,8.35,10.15,6.85,8.8,5.45,8,5.6,7.9,5.55,4.65,4.25,8.7,7.4,5.35,6.35)
x5<-c(5.65,6.95,5.75,7.7,5.05,6.2,2.75,4,3.3,2.25,2.15,3.2,2.85,2.7,5.6,6.1,5,5.05,6,4.1,5.5,3.05,5.05,3.35,4.75,3.25,2.7,2.4,5.1,4.4,3.15,3.9)
x6<-c(2.4,3.15,2.1,3.9,2.05,2.5,1.2,1.5,1.4,0.75,1,1.6,1.55,1.4,1.95,2.4,1.85,1.9,2.6,1.5,1.85,1.5,1.9,1.1,1.95,1.15,0.95,1.25,2.25,1.6,1.2,1.25)
x7<-c(3.25,3.8,3.65,3.8,3,3.7,1.55,2.5,1.9,1.5,1.15,1.6,1.3,1.3,3.65,3.7,3.15,3.15,3.4,2.6,3.65,1.55,3.15,2.25,2.8,2.1,1.75,1.15,2.85,2.8,1.95,2.65)
x8<-c(0.33,0.36,0.4,0.35,0.49,0.38,0.29,0.27,0.4,0.37,0.32,0.38,0.44,0.35,0.46,0.4,0.25,0.37,0.38,0.33,0.39,0.41,0.27,0.36,0.25,0.34,0.36,0.42,0.34,0.45,0.32,0.63)
x9<-c(19,21,18,22,12,20,11,19,9,8,7,8,6,7,16,19,25,17,18,16,19,8,23,12,23,12,10,6,17,13,12,8)
x10<-c(0.065,0.076,0.073,0.076,0.06,0.074,0.031,0.05,0.038,0.03,0.023,0.032,0.026,0.026,0.073,0.074,0.063,0.063,0.068,0.052,0.073,0.031,0.063,0.045,0.056,0.042,0.035,0.023,0.057,0.056,0.039,0.053)
reg=lm(y~x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10)
reg
Di=cooks.distance(lm)
Di
plot1<-plot(Di,pch=19,type="o",col="darkslategray1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign a colors vector before plotting with `ifelse`:

```
colors <- ifelse(Di > 1, "red", "darkslategray1")
plot(Di, pch = 19, type = "o", col = colors)
```

Or use `ifelse` directly in the plot code.

```
plot(Di, pch = 19, type = "o", 
     col = ifelse(Di > 1, "red", "darkslategray1"))
```